# Contour integral of $e^z / (z-1)^n$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polynomials, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am attempting to evaluate the following contour integral: 
\begin{equation*}
\oint_{C(i,2)} \frac{e^z}{(z-1)^n} \,\text{d}z
\end{equation*}
where $C(i,2)$ is the circle of radius 2 around $i$, $\forall\; n \in \mathbb{N}$. I attempted to use Cauchy's Integral formula, letting
\begin{equation*}
f_{n}(z) = \frac{e^z}{(z-1)^{n-1}}
\end{equation*}
$\forall\; n \in \mathbb{N}$, so then
\begin{align*}
f_n(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} &\oint_{C(i,2)} \frac{f_n(z)}{z - 1} \,\text{d}z \\
\frac{2 \pi i e}{(1-1)^{n-1}} = &\oint_{C(i,2)} \frac{e^z}{(z-1)^n} \,\text{d}z
\end{align*}
But this is clearly undefined. Is there some key piece of understanding I'm missing with regards to this method or is there an entirely different tactic I am meant to take (or better yet, a result that simplifies this entirely)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't apply this formula in this case because $f_n$ is not holomorphic in the contour. But you can use this generalised Cauchy formula :
$$f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\, dz$$
$$\oint_{C(i,2)} \frac{e^z}{(z-1)^n} \,\text{d}z=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}\frac{de^z}{dz^{n-1}}(1)=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}e^1= \frac{2\pi e i}{(n-1)!}$$

Comment: All too easy (+1)

Comment: Forgot this formula even existed. Thanks!